# Does the default zip(a,b) in python cut off the final elements in some cases?

Tags: python, tuples, zip

I have a tuple that looks like this:

```
[("English story 1", "English story 2", "English story 3" etc), ("Spanish story 1", etc), ("Chinese story 1", etc), ("German story 1", etc) etc]
```

These are translations of the same paragraphs in different languages. They each should have the same number of elements, but in some cases that might be off. I'm not sure as these are first scraped off a website. I am zipping it using the default zip so that it looks like this:

```
[("English story 1", "Spanish Story 1", "Chinese story 1", "German Story 1", etc), ("English story 2", "Spanish story 2", etc) etc]
```

but the problem is that it seems that the last story in each translation is lost somewhere between finding them and zipping them. I've printed the lists / tuples out and seen the last story before the zip, then I zip it, and if I print again it is missing. I could show the exact cases but they are semi-large data sets. Any ideas? Is there a better way to zip? Do I have some learning to do? Thanks

Comment: look at [`itertools.ziplongest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Comment: Note that zipping may not work as expected if there is mismatch in order of translations or missing translations in the middle